# Merge array of Objects into Single Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, sorting

I have a  giant array of nested objects that looks something like this (add 76 more products and that paints a good picture):

```
[
  {
    "ProductID": 11,
    "ProductName": "Queso Cabrales",
    "SupplierID": 5,
    "CategoryID": 4,
    "QuantityPerUnit": "1 kg pkg.",
    "UnitPrice": 21,
    "UnitsInStock": 22,
    "UnitsOnOrder": 30,
    "ReorderLevel": 30,
    "Discontinued": false,
    "orders": [
      {
        "OrderID": 10248,
        "CustomerID": "VINET",
        "EmployeeID": 5,
        "OrderDate": "1996-07-04T05:00:00.000Z",
        "RequiredDate": "1996-08-01T05:00:00.000Z",
        "ShippedDate": "1996-07-16T05:00:00.000Z",
        "ShipVia": 3,
        "Freight": 32.38,
        "ShipName": "Vins et alcools Chevalier",
        "ShipAddress": "59 rue de l'Abbaye",
        "ShipCity": "Reims",
        "ShipRegion": null,
        "ShipPostalCode": "51100",
        "ShipCountry": "France",
        "order_details": {
          "OrderID": 10248,
          "ProductID": 11,
          "UnitPrice": 14,
          "Quantity": 12,
          "Discount": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "OrderID": 10296,
        "CustomerID": "LILAS",
        "EmployeeID": 6,
        "OrderDate": "1996-09-03T05:00:00.000Z",
        "RequiredDate": "1996-10-01T05:00:00.000Z",
        "ShippedDate": "1996-09-11T05:00:00.000Z",
        "ShipVia": 1,
        "Freight": 0.12,
        "ShipName": "LILA-Supermercado",
        "ShipAddress": "Carrera 52 con Ave. Bolívar #65-98 Llano Largo",
        "ShipCity": "Barquisimeto",
        "ShipRegion": "Lara",
        "ShipPostalCode": "3508",
        "ShipCountry": "Venezuela",
        "order_details": {
          "OrderID": 10296,
          "ProductID": 11,
          "UnitPrice": 16.8,
          "Quantity": 12,
          "Discount": 0
        }
      } ... etc.
```

I need to loop through Orders and Order_Details and merge each Product's orders into a single array.  A product has multiple order and each order has a single order detail so my ideal output would look something like this:

```
  {
        "ProductID": 11,
        "ProductName": "Queso Cabrales",
        "SupplierID": 5,
        "CategoryID": 4,
        "QuantityPerUnit": "1 kg pkg.",
        "UnitPrice": 21,
        "UnitsInStock": 22,
        "UnitsOnOrder": 30,
        "ReorderLevel": 30,
        "Discontinued": false,
        "OrderID": [10248, 10296]
        "CustomerID":[ "VINET", "LILAS"]
        "EmployeeID":[ 5,  6]
        "OrderDate":[ "1996-07-04T05:[0:[0.000Z", "1996-09-03T05:00:00.000Z"]
        "RequiredDate":[ "1996-08-01T05:[0:[0.000Z", "1996-10-01T05:00:00.000Z"]
        "ShippedDate":[ "1996-07-16T05:[0:[0.000Z", "1996-09-11T05:00:00.000Z"]
        "ShipVia":[ 3, 1]
        "Freight":[ 32.38, 0.12]
        "ShipName":[ "Vins et alcools Chevalier", "LILA-Supermercado"]
        "ShipAddress":[ "59 rue de l'Abbaye", "Carrera 52 con Ave. Bolívar #65-98 Llano Largo"]
        "ShipCity":[ "Reims", "Barquisimeto"]
        "ShipRegion":[ null, "Lara"]
        "ShipPostalCode":[ "51100", "3508"]
        "ShipCountry":[ "France", "Venezuela"]
        "OrderID":[ 10248, 10296]
        "ProductID":[ 11, 11]
        "UnitPrice":[ 14, 16.8]
        "Quantity":[ 12, 12]
        "Discount":[ 0,  0]
}
```

My biggest issues with this are:

- accessing order_details as its nested within each orderID
- maintaining 1 product to multiple orders association (I managed to merge everything into one giant array and it nearly broke the internet)

I'm looking to send this to the client side to visualize with D3. If you can image a stacked area chart with a data input like this:

```
var graph = {
    Spicy-Ramen: {[  
        [380.00, 12-March-2015], [420.62, 19-March-2015] 
    ]},
    Miso-Soup: {[
        [230.99, 12-April-2015], [322.60, 22-May-2015] 
    ]},
    Vegetable-Shumai: {[
        [22.99, 12-June-2015], [121.20, 29-August-2015]
    ]}
}
```

I used _.merge and _.assign unsuccessfully - any support or a nudge in the right direction would be well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got it right, so I would recommend to make a few separate objects like **Products** and **Orders**, where each key of the object is the id of an element, so that your **Orders** object would be something like that:

```
var Orders = {
    11:{"ProductID":11,"ProductName":...},
    12:{"ProductID":12,"ProductName":...},
}
```

So you can easily reach order parameters by its id.

You can do the same thing to **order_details**, but I don't see any reason why not include its attributes to **Orders** object.

Comment: Interesting approach, I didn't think of doing it like that.  My initial thought was to create an array of separate tables, with each product owning one of those tables, and the array of orders and order_details owned by the product within that table.

Comment: I appreciate your input however, I'll likely get frustrated with my approach and attempt yours - I'll keep you updated!